# Debugging Tensorflow 2.0: Printing in a tf.function that crashes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to debug a relatively complex custom training method using custom loss functions, etc. In particular I am trying to debug an issue in a custom training step, which is compiled into a Tensorflow @function and fitted as a Keras compiled model. I want to be able to print out an intermediate value of a tensor in a function call that is crashing. The difficulty is that since tensors inside an @function are graph values and arent evaluated immediately, and since the function crashes during evaluation, it seems like the values aren't actually calculated. Here is a simple example:

```
class debug_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, width,depth,insize,outsize,batch_size):
        super(debug_model, self).__init__()
        self.width = width
        self.depth = depth
        self.insize = insize
        self.outsize = outsize
        
        self.net = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        self.net.add(tf.keras.Input(shape = (insize,)))
        for i in range(depth):
            self.net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(width,activation = 'swish'))
        self.net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(outsize))
    
    def call(self,ipts):
        
        return self.net(ipts)
    
    @tf.function
    def train_step(self,data):
        ipt, target = data
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape_1:
            tape_1.watch(ipt)
            y = self(ipt)

            tf.print('y:',y)
            assert False
            loss = tf.keras.losses.MAE(target,y)
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        loss_grad = tape_1.gradient(loss,trainable_vars)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(loss_grad, trainable_vars))
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(target, y)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

If you compile this model with some data of your choice and run it:

```
train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_tuple).batch(opt.batchSize)
train_set.shuffle(buffer_size = trainpoints)

model = debug_model(opt.width,opt.depth,in_size,out_size,batchSize)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=opt.lr)    
lr_sched = lambda epoch, lr: lr * 0.95**(1 / (8))    
cb_scheduler = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule = lr_sched, verbose = 1)
model.build((None,1))    
model.summary()    
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
    )
    
callbacks = [
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(path,
    verbose=2
),
cb_scheduler,
tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(path+'log.csv')
]
    
hist = model.fit(train_set,epochs = opt.nEpochs,callbacks = callbacks)
```

If you load this up and run it you will see that it exits due to the assertion error without printing. Is there a way I can force this tensor to evaluate so I can print it?

Comment: `assert False` will crash the function when the graph is built. `tf.print` is for printing things when actually evaluating the function (when it is called after being built). Simply remove the assertion.

Comment: I understand that the assertion is crashing the function, that's the only purpose of "assert False". This is an example of a "train_step" that crashes, which reproduces an issue that I am having with a more complex implementation that crashes for a reason I don't understand yet. The assertion here is a stand-in for the unknown crash cause that I am trying to diagnose.

Comment: Or is the point that the crash is happening before there are any values there at all, so there's nothing to print?

Comment: Yes, `assert` will crash the function when compiling, _not_ when it is actually running with "real" values, whereas `tf.print` will only print in the latter case, so that's probably not what you want. Perhaps this is more appropriate: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/Assert